# nginx 403 Forbidden on CentOS (Vagrant)

Tags: centos, nginx, vagrant

What I have checked so far:

Logs - they are empty, booted a new VM.

Permissions:

```
$ namei -l /var/www/awesome/    
f: /var/www/awesome/    
dr-xr-xr-x root     root     /    
drwxr-xr-x root     root     var    
drwxrwxr-x www-data www-data www
drwxrwxr-x www-data www-data awesome
```

Given 777 to the host OS folder that has the vagrant file.

Enabled SELinux.

Still, even inside the vm with curl localhost I get a 403.

Here is the nginx configuration for awesome.dev

```
server {
   listen                *:80;

   server_name           awesome.dev www.awesome.dev;
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;

   access_log            /var/log/nginx/awesome.dev.access.log;
   error_log             /var/log/nginx/awesome.dev.error.log;

   location / {
     root  /var/www/awesome;
     try_files $uri $uri/ index.php /index.php$is_args$args;
   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
     root  /var/www/awesome;
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
     fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
     include fastcgi_params;
   }
   sendfile off;
 }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Is SELinux set to enforcing?

Comment: @aairey SELinux is disabled. (sestatus)

Comment: Enabled SELinux, still getting 403.

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton nginx error and access logs are empty.

Comment: @user1502 Reduce error log level. I think we won't go far without your nginx configuration too.

Comment: @XavierLucas added the conf, how to reduce the log level? Do you mean add debug, e.g error_log /path/to/log debug; ?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with CentOS 7.  Resolved by:

```
Check getenforce
```

This should show 'Enforcing'

Then I ran `chcon` to change the httpd security context to allow access.

```
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/web/content
```

Reload Nginx

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Now my pages load.

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of `/var/www/awesome/` and its permissions?

If there is no `index.html`, `index.htm` or `index.php` file, nginx will be attempting to list directory content, which is by default forbidden (cf. [`autoindex`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex) documentation).